# Как найти дубликат изображения из других изображений?

Tags: python

У меня есть входное изображение и я должен найти похожие в папке с кучей картинок.
Я попробовал сделать через `PIL.ImageChops.difference` но мои изображения маленькие (50x50) и он считает их слишком похожими. Примеры - [image: первое изображение]

[image: второе изображение]

(предметы из игры the binding of isaac) я хочу принимать скриншот из игры с предметом и находить его в базе чтобы выдать нужную информацию. Сам предмет выглядит всегда одинаково, но фон может меняться.

Comment: Предмет это что глаз что ли?

Comment: В вопросе приведено 2 примера предмета из игры (а так их больше 1000), глаз и редиска

Comment: А вы не могли бы дать ссылку на архив с изображениями и тем что нужно найти. Не обязательно все можно процентов 5.

Comment: У меня есть одна задумка.